# How to Get Activity Ids of Activity Reaction in Swift

Tags: getstream-io

So I'm using Swift and I am trying to get all the comments activityId so that I can open them in another DetailViewController. Though I'm not sure how to go about this. below is what I think is the right way to go about it but i'm not sure how to get the activities. How should I go about this? I want to put them in an array of activityIds.

```
 Client.shared.reactions(forActivityId: activityPresenter!.activity.id, kindOf: .comment) {
        result in 
        if let values = try? result.get() {

        }
    }
```

[image]
I've added an image for clarification. Right now I'm using the DetailViewController which is the image shown. In this view, there is a section that says "2 more replies". Currently when I click on it, it doesn't segue anywhere. What I want to do is when I click on the comment that has replies, it will segue to a similar screen that shows those replies so users can comment and react to them.

Answer (score 0):

When using reactions, it is possible to request enriched activities that include both attached reactions by type and reaction counters.
Here is an example in Swift showing how to retrieve those enriched activities from a given feed :

```
// read bob's timeline and include most recent reactions to all activities and their total count
client.flatFeed(feedSlug: "timeline", userId: "bob")
.get(includeReactions: [.latest, .counts]) { result in /* ... */ }
```

Please find out more about it here in our documentation : https://getstream.io/docs/reactions_read_feeds/?language=swift#read_feeds_with_reactions

Comment: I'm not trying to do that, I already have the replies. What I want to do is click into the replies in the comments and see them. Which will then allow users to comment and react to the replies. I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that what I'm looking for is not possible. Reactions are different from Activities and have their own Ids ex. reactionId vs activityId so I can't use the DetailViewController to open a reaction. I've posted another question related to this here: [Does Stream.io for Swift have a "ReactionViewController" that works similarly to DetailViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147136/does-stream-io-for-swift-have-a-reactionviewcontroller-that-works-similarly-to)