# Does Stream.io for Swift have a "ReactionViewController" that works similarly to DetailViewController?

Tags: getstream-io

While working with Stream.io for Swift I've found that Activities have reactionId's associated to them. You can view the reactions to an Activity using the DetailViewController. I've shown a picture below as an example:

[image]

While testing it, I found that users can have reactions to reactions for example in the image you see "2 more replies". If you try to click to see those reactions nothing happens. I've figured out how to get the reactionIds of the Activity in the DetailViewController. But I was wondering if Stream.io has another view that acts like the DetailViewController but for reactions so you can view and react to reactions of reactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GetStream Swift SDK doesn't support this. You can open a feature request (or bug report) in the repo: https://github.com/GetStream/swift-activity-feed